# when I use react-native-track-player, can't play audio

Tags: android, react-native-track-player

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import TrackPlayer, {usePlaybackState} from 'react-native-track-player';
import IconButton from './IconButton';

function Player({url}) {
  const [iconName, setIconName] = useState('play-circle');
  const playbackState = usePlaybackState();

  useEffect(() => {
    setup();
  }, []);

  async function setup() {
    await TrackPlayer.setupPlayer({});
    await TrackPlayer.reset();

    await TrackPlayer.add({
      id: 'trackId',
      url: url,
      title: 'Example Track',
      artist: 'Example Artist',
    });
  }

  async function togglePlayback() {
    const currentTrack = await TrackPlayer.getActiveTrackIndex();
    if (currentTrack == null) {
      await setup();
    } else {
      console.log(playbackState, TrackPlayer.STATE_PLAYING);
      if (playbackState === TrackPlayer.STATE_PLAYING) {
        await TrackPlayer.pause();
        setIconName('play-circle');
      } else {
        await TrackPlayer.play();
        setIconName('pause-circle');
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <IconButton
      pressEvent={togglePlayback}
      name={iconName}
      size={20}
      color="rgb(166, 166, 166)"
    />
  );
}

export default Player;
```

I passed a music link `http://music.wufazhuce.com/FkX6nZfSWVRRGacxHWGSZ2-SpjtP` to Player, The link is no problem, but here is an error,`error: {message: "Source error", code: "android-io-file-not-found"}`, It's very strange, I don't know why can't find this file and how to solve it, please help me.

I want to play the audio after I click the button

Answer (score 0):

Use `TrackPlayer.getCurrentTrack()` or something else that would make sense instead of `TrackPlayer.getActiveTrackIndex()` and use `State.Playing` instead of `TrackPlayer.STATE_PLAYING`.

I don't think `TrackPlayer` has `getActiveTrackIndex()` and `STATE_PLAYING` available.

Go through the documentation [Player](https://rntp.dev/docs/api/functions/player) or run `console.log(TrackPlayer)` to list available methods.

Visit documentation [State](https://rntp.dev/docs/api/constants/state) to see types of media state made available through `State`.

Hope this helps. I am using `^3.2.0`.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are trying to call the setup before having the url try to add the url in dependencys of useEffect so when your component intialzes first it will call all the useEffect and url will be null at that point of time so may be might be trowing that error